# How to extract uppercase substrings from a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, extract

I need a piece of code with which I can extract the substrings that are in uppercase from a string in Java.
For example:

```
"a:[AAAA|0.1;BBBBBBB|-1.90824;CC|0.0]"
```

I need to extract `CC` `BBBBBBB` and `AAAA`

Comment: This is a job for [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with [`String[] split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). The only problem can be with empty strings, but it's easy to filter them out:

```
String str = "a:[AAAA|0.1;BBBBBBB|-1.90824;CC|0.0]";
String[] substrings = str.split("[^A-Z]+");
for (String s : substrings)
{
    if (!s.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AAAA
BBBBBBB
CC
```

Comment: This also returned single uppercase chars from a mixed case string;

Answer (score 5):

This should demonstrate the proper syntax and method. More details can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

```
String myStr = "a:[AAAA|0.1;BBBBBBB|-1.90824;CC|0.0]";
Pattern upperCase = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = upperCase.matcher(myStr);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    results.add(matcher.group());
}

for (String s : results) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The `[A-Z]+` part is the regular expression which does most of the work. There are a lot of strong regular expression tutorials if you want to look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to extract all the uppercase letter use `[A-Z]+`, if you want just uppercase substring, meaning that if you have lowercase letters you don't need it (`HELLO` is ok but `Hello` is not) then use `\b[A-Z]+\b`

Comment: Word boundary - you can read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Actually the way to use the regex is "\\b[^A-Z]+\\b" and the output for "JOHN DOE is a name" is JOHN DOE using string.split in Java

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a replace all regular expression to turn the character you don't want into a delimiter, perhaps something like this:

1. str.replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", " ")
2. Trim any leading or trailing spaces.
3. Then, if you wish, you can call str.split(" ")

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MatcherDemo {

    private static final String REGEX = "[A-Z]+";
    private static final String INPUT = "a:[AAAA|0.1;BBBBBBB|-1.90824;CC|0.0]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
       //  get a matcher object
       Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
       List<String> sequences = new Vector<String>();
       while(m.find()) {
           sequences.add(INPUT.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
       }
    }
}
```